# Selenium-webdriver wait(condition, timeout) timeout is ignored

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, timeout, wait

I am attempting to wait for a success toast after editing an item in a table.

It appears the selenium is not taking into account the timeout time that I have provided to the wait function.

What am I missing? I shouldn't have to provide a ridiculously high number(which only works sometimes) to make this work when I only need ~7 seconds.

```
driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(driver.findElement(By.className('alert-success'))), 999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999).then(function () {
        return driver.findElement(By.className('table-striped')).getText().then(function (text) {
            expect(tableState).toNotEqual(text);
            done();
            driver.quit();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Why are you doing a driver.quit() inside the wait?  Also, are you defining an implicit wait after you initialize the driver?

Comment: This is on the last test in a long line of them which is why the driver.quit() is there, I could probably move it but this works fine in other places. 

The driver is definitely working fine as all tests up to this point work.

Comment: I'm not using javascript, but you might want to consider using the click instead of visible condition - here's my java code:

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(getElement(objName)));

Comment: @BillHileman I guess `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated` will also work.

Comment: @JayeshDoolani Has it.  

Found that while looking for the ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable equivalent for javascript( it's until.elementIsEnabled() ) and it appears to work correctly.

This doesn't actually answer my original question of why the timeout I was setting is being ignored, but it does complete the test in the way I was expecting. Thanks guys.

Comment: @dittmanc if you set an implicit wait, there can be bugs when combining with explicit waits like you've done here. However, it's probably more likely that the element with `.alert-success` is visible before it becomes enabled, so it was returning before you wanted it to.

Comment: @mrfreester Ah thanks I knew using both wasn't necessarily best practice, but I didn't know there could be bugs from it.